# How to use grouped_ggwithinstats() function from ggstatsplot package correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2, anova, ggstatsplot

I am trying to use `grouped_ggwithinstats()` function from `ggstatsplot` package:

I have this data set:

```
df <- structure(list(time = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L), group1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "C 1", "C 1", "C 1", "C 1", "C 2", "C 2", "C 2", 
"C 2"), group2 = c("Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", 
"Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z"), value = c(100L, 60L, 30L, 
32L, 100L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 100L, 17L, 17L, 8L, 100L, 35L, 36L, 22L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16"))

   time group1 group2 value
1     0      A      Z   100
2     1      A      Z    60
3     2      A      Z    30
4     3      A      Z    32
5     0      B      Z   100
6     1      B      Z     2
7     2      B      Z     3
8     3      B      Z     1
9     0    C 1      Z   100
10    1    C 1      Z    17
11    2    C 1      Z    17
12    3    C 1      Z     8
13    0    C 2      Z   100
14    1    C 2      Z    35
15    2    C 2      Z    36
16    3    C 2      Z    22
```

Using this code:

```
library(ggstatsplot)

ggbetweenstats(
  data = df,
  x = time,
  y = value,
  type = "nonparametric", 
  plot.type = "box",
  centrality.plotting = FALSE 
)
```

[image]
I now would like to group by `group1` and mark the dots with each group:
So when I do:

```
grouped_ggbetweenstats(
  data = df,
  x = time,
  y = value,
  grouping.var = group1,
  type = "nonparametric", 
  plot.type = "box",
  centrality.plotting = FALSE 
)
```

[image]

I do not understand the difference between `ggwithinstats` vs. `ggbetweenstats` in relation to `grouped_ggbetweenstats()` and `grouped_ggwithinstats()` the latter giving the Error:

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1
```

What I try to test is using repeated anova, if the changes over timepoint 0,1,2,3 are significant within each group. e.g. in GroupA, Group B, Group C 1, Group C 2.

Comment: I think the error happens because with `within` you can compare the repeated within group, but you only have one value within a group, right?

Comment: Maybe the [`ez`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ez/index.html) package can be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `grouped_ggwithinstats()` correctly, but you are getting all these warnings because there just isn't enough data to run hypothesis testing and estimation.

You have one datum per condition per group, and so no statistical tests can be run, and thus the subtitles and captions are empty.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(ggstatsplot)
#> You can cite this package as:
#>      Patil, I. (2021). Visualizations with statistical details: The 'ggstatsplot' approach.
#>      Journal of Open Source Software, 6(61), 3167, doi:10.21105/joss.03167

df <- tibble(time = c(
  0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L,
  2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L
), group1 = c(
  "A", "A", "A", "A", "B",
  "B", "B", "B", "C 1", "C 1", "C 1", "C 1", "C 2", "C 2", "C 2",
  "C 2"
), group2 = c(
  "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z",
  "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z"
), value = c(
  100L, 60L, 30L,
  32L, 100L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 100L, 17L, 17L, 8L, 100L, 35L, 36L, 22L
))

df %>%
  group_by(group1, time) %>%
  count()
#> # A tibble: 16 × 3
#> # Groups:   group1, time [16]
#>    group1  time     n
#>    <chr>  <int> <int>
#>  1 A          0     1
#>  2 A          1     1
#>  3 A          2     1
#>  4 A          3     1
#>  5 B          0     1
#>  6 B          1     1
#>  7 B          2     1
#>  8 B          3     1
#>  9 C 1        0     1
#> 10 C 1        1     1
#> 11 C 1        2     1
#> 12 C 1        3     1
#> 13 C 2        0     1
#> 14 C 2        1     1
#> 15 C 2        2     1
#> 16 C 2        3     1

grouped_ggwithinstats(
  data = df,
  x = time,
  y = value,
  grouping.var = group1,
  type = "nonparametric",
  pairwise.comparisons = FALSE,
  centrality.plotting = FALSE
)
#> Warning: Groups with fewer than two data points have been dropped.
#> Groups with fewer than two data points have been dropped.
#> Groups with fewer than two data points have been dropped.
#> Groups with fewer than two data points have been dropped.
#> Warning in max(data$density): no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
#> Warning: Computation failed in `stat_ydensity()`
#> Caused by error in `$<-.data.frame`:
#> ! replacement has 1 row, data has 0
#> Warning: Groups with fewer than two data points have been dropped.
#> Groups with fewer than two data points have been dropped.
#> Groups with fewer than two data points have been dropped.
#> Groups with fewer than two data points have been dropped.
#> Warning in max(data$density): no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
#> Warning: Computation failed in `stat_ydensity()`
#> Caused by error in `$<-.data.frame`:
#> ! replacement has 1 row, data has 0
#> Warning: Groups with fewer than two data points have been dropped.
#> Groups with fewer than two data points have been dropped.
#> Groups with fewer than two data points have been dropped.
#> Groups with fewer than two data points have been dropped.
#> Warning in max(data$density): no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
#> Warning: Computation failed in `stat_ydensity()`
#> Caused by error in `$<-.data.frame`:
#> ! replacement has 1 row, data has 0
#> Warning: Groups with fewer than two data points have been dropped.
#> Groups with fewer than two data points have been dropped.
#> Groups with fewer than two data points have been dropped.
#> Groups with fewer than two data points have been dropped.
#> Warning in max(data$density): no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
#> Warning: Computation failed in `stat_ydensity()`
#> Caused by error in `$<-.data.frame`:
#> ! replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed the strategy and now it works.

Comment: Could you direct me to a page where the difference between `ggbetweenstats` and `ggwithinstats` is demonstrated, ideally with an example. Many thanks.

Comment: You can have a look at these articles and see if that's helpful:  https://indrajeetpatil.github.io/ggstatsplot/articles/